# Ten balls are thrown randomly into three buckets.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

how would you solve this problem? 
Ten balls are thrown randomly into three buckets. Compute the probability that each bucket contains at least one ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is assuming that the balls can only land in the three buckets and each bucket is equally likely as a target. 
The easier way to do it would be thinking go it in the other direction: What is the probability that at least one bucket has no balls? 
Let the aforementioned probability be: P 
Therefore, the answer you require is: 1 - P. 
To calculate P: 
$P = $ probability that ball lands only in any 2 buckets($=P_1$) $+$ probability that ball lands in only one bucket($=P_2$)
$$
P_1 = {3\choose 2} (\frac{2}{3})^{10}
$$
as, you choose any two buckets in which are the balls are supposed to fall ${3\choose 2}$ and the probability that the ball falls only in those two is $\frac{2}{3}$. 
Since you are throwing 10 balls, simply multiple $\frac{2}{3}$ 10 times to give $P_1$
$$
P_2 = {3\choose 1} (\frac{1}{3})^{10}
$$
as, you choose only buckets in which are the balls are supposed to fall ${3\choose 1}$ and the probability that the ball falls only in that bucket is $\frac{1}{3}$. 
Since you are throwing 10 balls, simply multiple $\frac{1}{3}$ 10 times to give $P_1$

Therefore, your answer is:
$$
1 - P_1 - P_2 = 1 - {3\choose 2} (\frac{2}{3})^{10} - {3\choose 1} (\frac{1}{3})^{10}
$$